# Postfix: smtpd_*_restrictions ending in reject

Tags: postfix

I've a Postfix server running for my own email and everything works fine. While I was upgrading the machine and decided to review the security settings / read and implement some best practices online and most online tutorials tell me to set `smtpd_client_restrictions` under `main.cf` similarly to this:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org
```

And at the same time I also see people setting the `submission` service under `master.cf` as:

```
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
 (...)
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

**My question**: Why does the `smtpd_client_restrictions` under `submission` ends with `reject` and under `main.cf` nobody recommends ending the list with `reject`? Aren't they just the same thing according to the docs:

> -o name=value (short form)
>                        Override the named main.cf configuration  parameter.  The
>                        parameter  value  can  refer to other parameters as $name
>                        etc., just like in main.cf.  See postconf(5) for  syntax.
>   http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html

Also,

> Restrictions are applied in the order as specified; the first
>   restriction that matches wins. http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions

If "the first restriction that matches wins" rule really applies won't ending it with `reject` would cause it to be impossible to send email at all?

Thank you.

Comment: You have `permit_` parameters. Those might match.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so If `permit_sasl_authenticated` checks no further restrictions will be tested?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so do you think that `smtpd_client_restrictions`, `smtpd_sender_restrictions`, `smtpd_relay_restrictions` should all have `reject` as the last check in `main.cf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's redundant. If you reach the end and haven't matched anything, the default is `reject` anyway. But having it there makes that explicit for people who don't know what the default is.

Comment: Hmm... I was under the impression that the default is `permit` because of this: "The end of each list is equivalent to a PERMIT result"  http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Comment: Well, that's confusing. Elsewhere in the docs it states that reject is the default. Maybe you'd better be explicit. I don't trust the docs anymore. :)